# How to remove Apple Push Notification from one device if another device received and handled the same notification?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In the Mail app for iOS - if one device received a new email notification, the same email notification will automatically disappear from other same user devices.

Is there some code inside

```
 optional func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void){

 }
```

that tells the mail server this email was read?

And if yes, how does the mail server "cancel" the notification to the other devices?

Comment: your question is too broad, in here you need to handle with some ids

Comment: Sorry don't understand what you mean by ids?

Comment: I figured out some work around, not sure though if it's best way to think about it... Upon receiving a push notification on 1 device, if the user handles that notification the above delegate function sends to the server that this notification is handled on this device, then the server in turn sends to the other devices a notification reducing the badge number possibly with no sound or whatever...